# Cannot attach to SQL Server database from docker compose

Tags: sql-server, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 docker images: Web API and SQL Server.
There is a test database located in contaner's `/var/opt/mssql/data/`(it's just for test, prod database located on server and mounted via `volume`)

My docker-compose is:

```
version: "3.9"  # optional since v1.27.0
services:
  web_api:
    image: web_api
    container_name: web_api_application
    volumes:
      - /root/smData/uploads:/app/uploads
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - sql
  sql:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest"
    container_name: sql_server2022
    ports:
      - "1433:1433" 
    volumes:
      - /root/smData:/app
    environment:
      - ACCEPT_EULA=y
      - SA_PASSWORD=MyVery$trogPas$
      - attach_dbs=[{"dbName":"sm3","dbFiles":["/var/opt/mssql/data/sm3.mdf","/var/opt/mssql/data/sm3_log.ldf"]}]
```

`sm3` database was created by SSMS connected to server, and then deattached. I also checked that `sm3.mdf` and `sm3_log.ldf` exist in container's folder `/var/opt/mssql/data`

So, when I run `docker compose up` I'm expecting that there is attached `sm3` database in database explorer. But it isn't.

Container logs are non readable, as an example:

```
sql_server2022       | D
sql_server2022       | a
sql_server2022       | t
sql_server2022       | a
sql_server2022       | b
sql_server2022       | a
sql_server2022       | s
sql_server2022       | e
sql_server2022       |  
sql_server2022       | '
sql_server2022       | m
sql_server2022       | s
sql_server2022       | d
sql_server2022       | b
sql_server2022       | '
sql_server2022       |  
sql_server2022       | r
sql_server2022       | u
sql_server2022       | n
sql_server2022       | n
sql_server2022       | i
sql_server2022       | n
sql_server2022       | g
sql_server2022       |  
sql_server2022       | t
sql_server2022       | h
sql_server2022       | e
sql_server2022       |  
sql_server2022       | u
sql_server2022       | p
sql_server2022       | g
sql_server2022       | r
sql_server2022       | a
sql_server2022       | d
sql_server2022       | e
sql_server2022       |  
sql_server2022       | s
sql_server2022       | t
sql_server2022       | e
sql_server2022       | p
sql_server2022       |  
sql_server2022       | f
sql_server2022       | r
sql_server2022       | o
sql_server2022       | m
sql_server2022       |  
sql_server2022       | v
sql_server2022       | e
sql_server2022       | r
sql_server2022       | s
sql_server2022       | i
sql_server2022       | o
sql_server2022       | n
sql_server2022       |  
sql_server2022       | 9
sql_server2022       | 5
sql_server2022       | 4
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is logs of MS SQL server located in `var/opt/mssql/log`

```
root@smdev2:~/smData# docker exec -it 248f7e4feb41 "bash"
mssql@248f7e4feb41:/$ cd /var/opt/mssql/log
mssql@248f7e4feb41:/var/opt/mssql/log$ cat setup*.log
cat: 'setup*.log': No such file or directory
mssql@248f7e4feb41:/var/opt/mssql/log$ ls
HkEngineEventFile_0_133354055990690000.xel  HkEngineEventFile_0_133354381236480000.xel  errorlog  errorlog.1  errorlog.2  log.trc  log_1.trc  sqlagentstartup.log  system_health_0_133354056062360000.xel  system_health_0_133354381250250000.xel
mssql@248f7e4feb41:/var/opt/mssql/log$ cat errorlog         
2023-08-02 08:22:02.57 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU5) (KB5026806) - 16.0.4045.3 (X64) 
    May 26 2023 12:52:08 
    Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
    Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS) <X64>
2023-08-02 08:22:02.58 Server      UTC adjustment: 0:00
2023-08-02 08:22:02.59 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2023-08-02 08:22:02.59 Server      All rights reserved.
2023-08-02 08:22:02.60 Server      Server process ID is 364.
2023-08-02 08:22:02.60 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
2023-08-02 08:22:02.61 Server      Registry startup parameters: 
     -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
     -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
     -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
2023-08-02 08:22:02.62 Server      SQL Server detected 1 sockets with 1 cores per socket and 1 logical processors per socket, 1 total logical processors; using 1 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:02.64 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:02.65 Server      Detected 1571 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:02.66 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2023-08-02 08:22:02.66 Server      Detected pause instruction latency: 40 cycles.
2023-08-02 08:22:02.67 Server      Page exclusion bitmap is enabled.
2023-08-02 08:22:02.71 Server      Buffer pool extension is not supported on Linux platform.
2023-08-02 08:22:02.72 Server      Buffer Pool: Allocating 262144 bytes for 167220 hashPages.
2023-08-02 08:22:02.89 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary.
2023-08-02 08:22:03.34 Server      Installing Client TLS certificates to the store.
2023-08-02 08:22:03.36 Server      Error searching first file in /var/opt/mssql/security/ca-certificates: 3(The system cannot find the path specified.)
2023-08-02 08:22:03.37 Server      CPU vectorization level(s) detected:  SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE41 SSE42 AVX AVX2 POPCNT BMI1 BMI2
2023-08-02 08:22:03.44 Server      Successfully initialized the TLS configuration. Allowed TLS protocol versions are ['1.0 1.1 1.2']. Allowed TLS ciphers are ['ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA'].
2023-08-02 08:22:03.52 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1, 
2023-08-02 08:22:03.54 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2023-08-02 08:22:03.56 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x0000000000000001:0 Active CPU mask: 0x0000000000000001:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:03.59 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:03.62 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on lowend machine.
2023-08-02 08:22:03.65 Server      [INFO] Created Extended Events session 'hkenginexesession'
2023-08-02 08:22:03.67 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: enabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:03.74 Server      Total Log Writer threads: 1, Node CPUs: 1, Nodes: 1, Log Writer threads per CPU: 1, Log Writer threads per Node: 2
2023-08-02 08:22:03.77 Server      CLR version v4.0.30319 loaded.
2023-08-02 08:22:03.78 Server      clwb is selected for pmem flush operation.
2023-08-02 08:22:03.79 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2023-08-02 08:22:03.86 spid8s      [1]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1. ConcurrentGAMUpdate: 1. ConcurrentSGAMUpdate: 1, CleanupUnderUserTransaction: 0. TranLevelPVS: 0
2023-08-02 08:22:03.90 spid8s      Starting up database 'master'.
2023-08-02 08:22:04.23 spid8s      [32762]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1. ConcurrentGAMUpdate: 1. ConcurrentSGAMUpdate: 1, CleanupUnderUserTransaction: 0. TranLevelPVS: 0
2023-08-02 08:22:04.27 spid16s     [32767]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1. ConcurrentGAMUpdate: 1. ConcurrentSGAMUpdate: 1, CleanupUnderUserTransaction: 0. TranLevelPVS: 0
2023-08-02 08:22:04.29 spid8s      Starting up database 'model_replicatedmaster'.
2023-08-02 08:22:04.30 spid16s     Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2023-08-02 08:22:04.34 spid16s     The resource database build version is 16.00.4045. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:04.46 spid16s     [3]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1. ConcurrentGAMUpdate: 1. ConcurrentSGAMUpdate: 1, CleanupUnderUserTransaction: 0. TranLevelPVS: 0
2023-08-02 08:22:04.49 spid16s     Starting up database 'model'.
2023-08-02 08:22:04.67 spid8s      [32761]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1. ConcurrentGAMUpdate: 1. ConcurrentSGAMUpdate: 1, CleanupUnderUserTransaction: 0. TranLevelPVS: 0
2023-08-02 08:22:04.70 spid8s      Starting up database 'model_msdb'.
2023-08-02 08:22:04.86 spid8s      Resource governor reconfiguration succeeded.
2023-08-02 08:22:04.88 spid8s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:04.91 spid22s     External governance manager initialized
2023-08-02 08:22:04.92 spid22s     Attribute synchronization manager initialized
2023-08-02 08:22:04.93 spid8s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:04.95 spid8s      XE session 'system_health' started.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.06 spid8s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2023-08-02 08:22:05.05 spid19s     A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.08 spid19s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433] accept sockets 1.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.08 spid8s      Server name is '248f7e4feb41'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.15 spid19s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433] accept sockets 1.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.18 Server      Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1434] accept sockets 1.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.20 spid16s     Clearing tempdb database.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.18 Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434] accept sockets 1.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.20 Server      Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening locally on port 1434.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.21 spid27s     Always On: The availability replica manager is starting. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.23 spid19s     Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1431] accept sockets 1.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.24 spid28s     [4]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1. ConcurrentGAMUpdate: 1. ConcurrentSGAMUpdate: 1, CleanupUnderUserTransaction: 0. TranLevelPVS: 0
2023-08-02 08:22:05.27 spid27s     Always On: The availability replica manager is waiting for the instance of SQL Server to allow client connections. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.30 spid28s     Starting up database 'msdb'.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.30 spid19s     Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1431] accept sockets 1.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.32 Server      Common language runtime (CLR) functionality initialized.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.33 spid19s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.50 spid16s     [2]. Feature Status: PVS: 0. CTR: 0. ConcurrentPFSUpdate: 1. ConcurrentGAMUpdate: 1. ConcurrentSGAMUpdate: 1, CleanupUnderUserTransaction: 0. TranLevelPVS: 0
2023-08-02 08:22:05.52 spid16s     Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.61 spid16s     The tempdb database has 1 data file(s).
2023-08-02 08:22:05.62 spid27s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.62 spid27s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.64 spid27s     Service Broker manager has started.
2023-08-02 08:22:05.66 spid8s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

Comment: I can read that log fine, I just need to turn my head on its side. What does the SQL Server log say? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-docker-container-troubleshooting?view=sql-server-ver16&pivots=cs1-bash#errorlogs

Comment: How have you determined that the database isn't attached? e.g.: Can you connect to the instance with SSMS and see which databases it has? `attach_dbs` isn't a parameter advertised by [`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server`](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) so what do you think it does? Do you have a startup script that uses that parameter to attach database(s)?

Comment: oic... `attach_dbs` was a parameter for the old [`microsoft/mssql-server-windows-express`](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/windows/mssql-server-windows-express) image.

Comment: I suspect that the issue here is with the attach_dbs environment variable. In YAML, [...] represents an array or list, and you need to escape the square brackets to ensure the correct parsing of this environment variable.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning oh, it means that 'attach_dbs' would not work on standard server? But how to use database in container, and keep data persisted?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I added logs in question. No problems there. I believe it was a joke about turning head, but I spent 15 hours before posted question, so I'm not smiling :(

Comment: You start by reading the [`mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server` image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-mssql-server) where it says... _You can also use the tools in an entrypoint.sh script to do things like create databases or logins, attach databases, import data, or other setup tasks. See this example of [using an entrypoint.sh and setup.sql scripts to create a database](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-customize)._

Comment: @ZaferCavdar well, I tried different ways of this parameter. I want to believe that the problem is somewhere in one symbol, but a cannot find it. I will be appreciated if you could show fully correct parameter so I can test it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @AlwaysLearning, I've managed to attach my database. I had to download [this repo](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/tree/master/linux/preview/examples/mssql-customize), and change `setup.sql` with

```
EXEC sp_attach_db @dbname = N'myDb',   
    @filename1 =   
N'/app/myDb_Data.mdf',   
    @filename2 =   
N'/app/myDb_Log.ldf';
GO
```

But also I had to change a bit docker file with adding root user when grant permissions to scripts. Full docker file is:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2022-latest

# Create a config directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/config
WORKDIR /usr/config

# Bundle config source
COPY . /usr/config

USER root
# Grant permissions for to our scripts to be executable
RUN chmod +x /usr/config/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/config/configure-db.sh

USER mssql

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

And also removed `- attach_dbs` from docker-compose file